# Remove single characters from list

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

I am having trouble understanding why my code is failing to work.
I am trying to remove words from a list that are only one character in length:

```
line = ['word','a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
for words in line:
    if len(words) == 1:
        line.remove(words)
```

This code returns this (which looks to remove 'every other' single character):

```
>>> line
['word', 'b', 'd', 'f']
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't working properly and how to fix?

Comment: Very common mistake. Never modify a list while iterating through it. The answers below provide the correct method for achieving the desired result

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this:

```
line = ['word','a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
line = [i for i in line if len(i) > 1]
```

The problem with your code is that you are removing from list while iterating which is not safe. It will change the length of list:

```
line = ['word','a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
iterated = 0
removed = 0
for words in line:
    iterated += 1
    if len(words) == 1:
        line.remove(words)
        removed += 1

print line # ['word', 'b', 'd', 'f']
print iterated # 5
print removed # 4
```